# Compiler error using custom classes despite correct header being imported

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-errors

In my iOS app, I have an interface with parameter types which are classes I've created that inherit from `NSObject`.
Example:

```
- (void) addTarget:(Target *)target;
```

In this interface, I have `#include "Target.h"`, in which file the interface for `Target` is defined. However, whenever I use any classes I've built as above, I end up with this compiler error:

> Expected ')' before 'Target'

However, when I change the type of the parameter to a built-in type, it works just fine.  This is my first project in Objective C.  Is there something fundamental I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure that Target.h doesn't #import this header file? (the one where addTarget: is defined)?

Comment: Thanks @FirozeLafeer, that was the issue.  Removing the cyclic dependency fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, removing the cyclic dependencies fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to `#import "Target.h"`, or whatever header file your custom classes are declared in. Otherwise, the compiler will have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I just added clarification to my question along these lines -- Target.h is imported and the Target interface is declared within that file.  The Target interface is implemented in the Target.m file.